# Claim seems incorrect in 19.36b of Spivak's Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

In Spivak's Calculus chapter 19, problem 36*b* there is the following claim to prove:

Given $a_1, \dots, a_n$ and $b_1, \dots, b_n$, with $\{b_n\}$ being nonincreasing and nonnegative,  and with $m \leq a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_k \leq M $ for all $k <= n$. Prove that

- $b_1 m \leq a_1 b_1 + \dots +a_n b_n \leq b_1 M$, and in general:
- $b_k m \leq a_k b_k + \dots +a_n b_n \leq b_k M$

I managed to prove the first claim easily, but I struggled with the second, so I looked up the solution. The author simply applies the first result for $ a_k, \dots, a_n$ and $ b_k, \dots, b_n$, and concludes that the inequality must hold.

Except that from $m \leq a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n \leq M $ it does not necessarily follow that $m \leq a_k + \dots + a_n \leq M $, so in my opinion the reasoning is incorrect.

Furthermore, as a counterexample, if we consider $a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}; b_n = 1$ with $m=0.75, M=1$, it's easy to see, that with n=3 and k=2 the claim doesn't hold:
$$ a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3 = a_2 + a_3 =  -\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} = -0.13\dot{8} $$
$$ b_2 m = 0.75 \nleq -0.13\dot{8}  $$

Is my reasoning correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: Even the first one is not correct: what if $b_1=0$ (or small enough if you want only positive values)?

Comment: @Sam sorry, that's my bad, b_n must be nonincreasing, not nondecreasing

Comment: Doesn't your counterexample fail for the requirement $m \le a_1 \le M$?

Comment: @Mark I don't believe so, $a_1 = \frac{(-1)^{1+1}}{1^2} = 1$

Comment: Yes I see. It seems to be a genuine counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I returned to this problem after a while, since Abel's lemma is used throughout the problems in conjunction with Cauchy's convergence test. While the original claim is not completely accurate, a similar proposition can be proved. In general

$$b_k (m - M) \leq a_k b_k + \dots +a_n b_n \leq b_k (M-m) \tag{1}$$

will hold. In practice it doesn't change much, since in most of the cases we just want to show that there is a bound that can be made small enough, so this was mainly just for my peace of mind.

*Proof:*
Let $s_k$ denote the partial sums of the $a_n$ sequence, i.e $s_k = \sum_{i=1}^k{a_i} $. Since $ m \le s_n \le M $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} $, we have $\left| s_i - s_j \right| \le  M - m  $, and in particular $m - M \le a_k + a_{k+1} + \dots + a_n \le M - m$. Now we can already use directly the first claim on $a_k, a_{k+1}, \dots, a_n$ and  $b_k, b_{k+1}, \dots, b_n$ with these new bounds to get to $(1)$.